# Qual a origem do "me vê" quando compramos algo?

Tags: português-brasileiro, expressões, expressões-populares

Em mercados, açougues, padarias, etc é comum ouvir a expressão "me vê uma coca cola" ou "me vê 5 pães". Por que essa expressão? Qual a origem e o que "me vê" tem a ver com comprar?

Comment: Isto parece-me ser uma extensão de uma aceção de *ver* comum no Brasil, que é 'procurar e trazer, buscar' ("Vai ver tua viola — e canta alguma cantiga da tua terra"; "Mandou ver caça e frutas"). Aqui *ver* até se compreende; daí para 'providenciar' é um passinho ("Vou ver uma cafezinho para você"); nos teus exemplos *ver* significa basicamente 'providenciar'. Vou tentar investigar isto mais a fundo.

Comment: Eu acho que se usa para evitar de dar ordens do tipo: Traga-me ou dê-me ou sirva-me. Brasileiro gosta de evitar esse type de formalismo além de não gostar dos pronomes. E "me da" realmente fica feio e sem educação. Faça o favor de me trazer um cafezinho, por favor? :) Nesse video, ela diz, porém, Vá.......Conversa de botiquim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em alguns dicionários, dentre outros significados, consta o significado de "providenciar", e "escolher".

Embora "escolher" possa se encaixar em alguns casos, o "providenciar" cobre todos os casos do uso do verbo "ver" questionado.

Notei que os dicionários que possuem "providenciar" (e "escolher") na definição de "ver", são de edições brasileiras, os de edições portuguesas, não a possuem. Vou citar apenas um de cada:

**Edição brasileira:** http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=ver

> vtdi 25 Providenciar algo para alguém, para uma finalidade; ir buscar,
>   trazer: Ele disse que vai ver um emprego para meu sobrinho na empresa
>   em que trabalha.

**Edição portuguesa:** https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/ver

Sobre quando o verbo "ver" passou a ter esses significados, não encontrei informações. Embora não seja impossível, me parece ser bem difícil (pelo menos bem trabalhoso) determinar quando. Uma alternativa seria vasculhar as diversas edições dos dicionários, para obter pelo menos uma aproximação de quando o significado foi catalogado, pois pode ter uma diferença de décadas de quando de fato começou a ser usado.